# How to get bool with `get_option()` when already registered setting with type `boolean`

Tags: php, options, settings-api

When I register a boolean setting using `register_setting()` I already pass the data type:

```php
        register_setting(
            option_group: '…',
            option_name: '…',
            args: [
                'type' => 'boolean',
                'description' => '…',
                'sanitize_callback' => function (mixed $value): bool {
                    return (bool) $value;
                },
                'show_in_rest' => false,
                'default' => false,
            ],
        );
```

However, when calling the option with `get_option()`, it still returns me a string value:

```php
"1"
```

I would like to compare values with `===` and would like to AVOID something like:

```php
(bool) get_option('…') === true
```

AND

```php
boolval(get_option('…')) === true;
```

I'm thinking of creating a helper function, that acts like a proxy, checks the data value of the setting for the given option name, convert it accordingly and return it.

Something like:

```php
    /**
     * Get option with a value converted into the correct data type as registered with `register_setting()`.
     */
    public static function getOption(string $optionName): mixed
    {
        $optionValue = get_option($optionName);

        $settingArgs = get_setting_args($optionName); // ???

        if (empty($settingArgs['type'])) {
            return $optionValue;
        }

        switch ($settingArgs['type']) {
            case 'string':
                return (string) $optionValue;
            case 'int':
                return (int) $optionValue;
            case 'bool':
                return (bool) $optionValue;
            case 'array':
                return (array) $optionValue;
            case 'object':
                return (object) $optionValue;
            case 'float':
                return (float) $optionValue;
            default:
                return $optionValue;
        }
    }
```

As marked in the code with `???` I have no idea to access the arguments of a registered setting in WordPress. How can I do so? Or should my goal be accomplished in another way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type argument is only relevant for the REST API and relatively new. If you want it to be enforced on `get_option()` you will need your own helper function, as you've noticed. This is probably for backwards compatibility reasons. I would avoid attempting to enforce this for all `get_options()` calls via a filter, and stick to using a helper function.

Registered settings are in the global `$wp_registered_settings` variable which you can retrieve with [`get_registered_settings()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_registered_settings/). The key of the array for your settings would be whatever you used for `option_name`.